# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using "freed" self in dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, sprite-kit

I have a game written using the new SpriteKit in iOS7. I have a customised `SKSpriteNode` which would fetch and display a Facebook profile picture. However, since it may take some time to load the picture. I tried to load the picture in background when I initialised the node and display it only when the picture is loaded. Here is code snippet I wrote:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


    // Code to load Facebook Profile picture
    // ...
    SKSpriteNode *fbFrame = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:facebookPicTexture];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


        // self is my customised SKSpriteNode - so here I just add a sprite node of
        // a facebook picture to myself as a child     
        [self addChild:fbFrame];
    });

});
```

It works fine normally. However, if the loading of Facebook profile pic is slow, the user may have already switch to another screen when the picture is loaded. In such case, `self` will actually be removed from the scene hierarchy and no reference will be made to it.

When I read the block doc, I think the async block will retain `self` and so I presume it will still be valid when the main thread block is called. It turns out from time to time if the pic loading is really slow and the second dispatch_async is called when self is removed from the hierarchy, a bad access error will occur at the line `[self addChild:fbFrame]`.

Am I understand the block memory management incorrectly? And is there a way to solve that kind of problem?

Comment: "if the pic loading is really slow and the second dispatch_async is called when self is removed from the hierarchy, a bad access error will occur at the line [self addChild:fbFrame]." Why would it do bad access if `self` is removed from the hierarchy. This is the part that doesn't make sense. As long as `self` points to a valid object (which is guaranteed here), sending messages to it should not crash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding of the memory management is correct, that the presence of `self` in this block will retain `self` until the dispatched block is completed. The solution is to not retain `self` while the block runs, by using a `weak` reference to `self` inside the block:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // do some stuff in background here; when done, then:

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [weakSelf addChild:fbFrame];
    });
});
```

You should review that block for any references to `self` (either explicit or implicitly by referencing an ivar directly), and replace them with `weakSelf`.

Or, (unlikely in this case) sometimes you'll see the `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` pattern where you must ensure that `self` isn't released during the execution of that nested block:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // do some stuff in background here; when done, then:

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (strongSelf) {
            // stuff that requires that if `self` existed at the start of this block, 
            // that it won't be released during this block
        }
    });
});
```

---

By the way, the other approach is to cancel the network request when the view controller is dismissed. This requires a more significant change (using a `NSOperation`-based approach rather than GCD; or use `NSURLSessionTask`-based approach that allows you to cancel the request), but it is the other way to tackle this.

Comment: How is any of this relevant to an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: @newacct The above is not trying to diagnose why the `SKSpriteNode` method `addChild` is generating `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, but merely is preventing the situation that resulted in the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in the first place. It's silly to keep the `SKSpriteNode` around so that the child can be added, even if the user has moved on (and it seems unremarkable that SpriteKit might not like it if you did that ... I don't know SpriteKit well enough to speculate). IMHO, it is inadvisable for network operations to hang on to UI objects (whether UIKit or SpriteKit) beyond that UI object's natural lifespan.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for that. After more diagnosis, I have an even more interesting findings: Since it's difficult to simulate a slow network consistently, I have artificially added a wait there to slow down the loading operations. Guess what? the app did not crash! So the crash is actually not consistent. Anyway, as you said the weak self solution can guard whatever cause to it - so I will give it a try.

Comment: @BillyKan Actually, Apple provides wonderful tools for simulating slow network, the network link conditioner. On a device that you've provisioned for development, there is a "Developer" section under "Settings" and you'll find the network link conditioner there. For simulator, on the Xcode menu, choose "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer Tools". That will take you to web site from which you can select "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode". Open up that DMG and double click on the "Network Link Conditioner", and install new pane in Settings in which you can have your Mac simulate slow networks.

Comment: @Rob, Ah, that's useful. Let me play around it. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to write like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);

objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"yourTag", @"Alive", OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{    
    // Code to load Facebook Profile picture
    // ...
    SKSpriteNode *fbFrame = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:facebookPicTexture];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSString *strAlive = (NSString *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @"yourTag");
        if (strAlive)
        {
            // self is my customised SKSpriteNode - so here I just add a sprite node of
            // a facebook picture to myself as a child     
            [self addChild:fbFrame];
        }
    });

});
dispatch_release(queue);
```

When you dont want the dispatch to continue procedure when the self (ViewController) is not visible anymore so write this:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"yourTag", nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

In:
`- viewWillDisapear` Or `- viewDidDisapear`
And renew calling the dispatch when you come back to than screen.

Comment: `self` is retained by the blocks, so there is no way it can be deallocated by the place where you check in the middle of the block

Comment: Right! I used this code for something else and didn't realize that in that way it is wrong